# extract substring from an input string - assembly

Tags: assembly

I'm a beginner in assembly language. I'm trying to extract the two number from an input string. E.g. a string input like this "22 * 158". I want to separate and save the first number, second number, and "*". Each one in different buffer.

This is what I came up so far. please, if you know better way or easiest way help me.

```
INBUF   DB  100, ?, 100 DUP ?
SPACE   EQU ' ' ;define space character
ANUM1   DB  3, ?, 3 DUP ?


GETNUM1:  ; To know how many digit in the first number
      LEA   SI, INBUF+2    ;Point to the input I got
      CMP   [SI], SPACE 
      JE    GET1
      INC   CL              ; increament the number of digit in the first number
      INC   SI              ; pint to the next character
      JMP   GETNUM1         ; back to loop
```

Then, loop back decrements SI as long the CL size is and move each SI to DI that pointed to ANUM1 like this:

```
SAVENUM1:
     MOV    AL, CL
     LEA    DI, ANUM1

LOOP2:
     DEC    SI
     MOV    DH, [SI]
     DEC    DI
     DEC    AL
     MOV    B[DI], DH
     CMP    AL, 0
     JNE    LOOP2
     RET
```

Then repeating the same thing for the second number.

Comment: A single pass is enough to tokenize and parse the string (or just tokenize it) but if your solution works why changing it? :) With time, as you'll get more used to assembly you can come back and adapt the code to your new standards. Don't focus too much on finding the best solution yet

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've not tested it yet but I think it will work. I'm asking because some time there is specific instructions or functions that help in this situation.